# how to send sensor data from arduino as a server to a jsp on tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, arduino, iot

I have Arduino with an ethernet shield. I want to send readings from the ultrasonic sensor to be displayed on a JSP that is on tomcat on my local machine. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Serial Communication of the Arduino you need to use the Serial-Comm library for your java Code, below is the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fazecast</groupId>
   <artifactId>jSerialComm</artifactId>
   <version>[2.0.0,3.0.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

After that pack the data received in an Object and send it to your JSP using :

```
request.setAttribute("key",object);
```

and then loop through your object to display the data within This 2 LINKS below might help you do it:

- http://classes.cec.wustl.edu/~SEAS-SVC-CSE132/weeks/6/studio/
- http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/

This Code will help you receiving data in your java code assuming that you know how to send data from Arduino code:

```
    SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    System.out.println("Select a port:");
    int i = 1;
    for(SerialPort port : ports)
        System.out.println(i++ +  ": " + port.getSystemPortName());
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int chosenPort = s.nextInt();

    SerialPort serialPort = ports[chosenPort - 1];
    if(serialPort.openPort())
        System.out.println("Port opened successfully.");
    else {
        System.out.println("Unable to open the port.");
        return;
    }

    serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

    Scanner data = new Scanner(serialPort.getInputStream());
    int value = 0;
    while(data.hasNextLine()){
        try{

        value = Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine());
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    catch(Exception e){}
}
System.out.println("Done.");
```

Comment: only a note: this doesn't use the Ethernet shield, but is a valid answer expecting that the Arduino is connected to the server PC over USB

Comment: I also thought of that and no doubt, it will work. I have worked with RxTx comm library previously. But I want to interact directly with the tomcat server containing my JSP file. It has something to do with Http response.